# Dynamically generate h:column based on list of hashmaps

Tags: jsf, dynamic, jsf-2, datatable

In my application I want to display a `<h:dataTable>` with managed bean properties. Currently this table is created from a `List<Folder>`. Now I want to change the `Folder` to something more dynamic. That's because I don't want to change the `Folder` class if I decide to add another field later. I would just have to add another entry in the `Map<String, Object>` instead of introducing a new field in `Folder`.

So, is it possible to bind a `List<Map<String, Object>>` to the `<h:dataTable>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *Is it possible to bind a List of HashMaps to the jsf component h:dataTable?*

That's only possible if you generate the necessary `<h:column>` tags with a view build time tag such as JSTL `<c:forEach>`.

Here's a concrete kickoff example, assuming that your environment supports EL 2.2:

```html
<h:dataTable value="#{bean.listOfMaps}" var="map">
    <c:forEach items="#{bean.listOfMaps[0].keySet().toArray()}" var="key">
        <h:column>
            #{map[key]}
        </h:column> 
    </c:forEach>
</h:dataTable>
```

*(if your environment doesn't support EL 2.2, you'd need to provide another getter which returns the map key set as a `String[]` or `List<String>`; also keep in mind that a `HashMap` is by nature unordered, you might want to use `LinkedHashMap` instead to maintain insertion order)*

When you're using Mojarra version older than 2.1.18, the disadvantage is that the `#{bean}` has to be request scoped (not view scoped). Or at least, the `<c:forEach items>` should refer a request scoped bean. A view scoped bean would otherwise be recreated on every single HTTP request as the `<c:forEach>` runs during view build time, when the view scope isn't availabe yet. If you absolutely need a view scoped bean for the `<h:dataTable>`, then you can always create a separate request scoped bean exclusively for `<c:forEach items>`. The solution would be to upgrade to Mojarra 2.1.18 or newer. For some background information, see also [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense)

JSF component libraries such as [PrimeFaces](http://www.primefaces.org) may offer a `<x:columns>` tag which makes this more easy, such as [`<p:dataTable>` with `<p:columns>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableDynamicColumns.jsf).

```
<p:dataTable value="#{bean.listOfMaps}" var="map">
    <p:columns value="#{bean.listOfMaps[0].keySet().toArray()}" var="key">
        #{map[key]}
    </p:columns>
</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: ah great that's what I was looking for. The only annoying thing is that I have to use the forEach. Somewhere I read that one could also implement some interface (don't remember the name) for your own data structure so that jsf knows how to render it. Is this possible or did I get something wrong there?

Comment: I think you get it wrong :) For the `<h:dataTable>`, the `UIColumn` children have really to be populated during view build time. The `<c:forEach>` is the only available iteration tag which runs during view build time.