# jstl foreach loop inside subtable not working properly

Tags: richfaces, jstl, jsf-1.2

I'm trying to get this pieace of code to work, but without any success:

```
<rich:subTable id="it" var="itemData" value="#{subCategoryData.dataValues}" 
                       onRowMouseOver="activateRow(this)"  onRowMouseOut="deactivateRow(this)">
            <rich:columnGroup rendered="#{!itemData.parent.calculated}">
                <rich:column id="item_edt_caption" styleClass="item-style">
                    <h:outputText value="#{itemData.parent.editedCaption}"/>
                </rich:column>


                <c:forEach var="item" varStatus="loop" items="${reportCenterSummaryController.dataSet.integerValues}" >

                <rich:column  >
                    <c:out value="${item}"></c:out>
                    <h:outputText value="#{itemData.dateValues[item]}" ></h:outputText>
                </rich:column>
            </c:forEach>
```

as it was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13835552/dynamic-columns-with-richfaces-4).

The `<c:out value="${item}"></c:out>` is displaying correctly the 0 1 2 3 4 .. values

but `<h:outputText value="#{itemData.dateValues[item]}" ></h:outputText>` is not displaying anything.

My environment is JSF 1.2 with richfaces and facelets in Tomcat 6.

Answer (score 0):

Noticed you are using **$** to print the value and **#** to fetch the array at the index, not sure if u can mix thigs that way. I would try using `<h:outputText value="#{itemData.dateValues[${item}]}" />` see what happens.

Comment: Look at this [post](http://www.ninthavenue.com.au/jsf-c-foreach-vs-ui-repeat) it might help